# IOS Swift IBAction behaviour when combining actions

Tags: ios, swift

I have a custom keyboard extension which works as expected but I am coming across some odd behaviour which I can't explain. It is designed primarily for data input into Excel spreadsheets, so the fewer the keystrokes the better.

I have 2 IBActions. 
Keypressed takes the value of the keypresses and inserts it into the current cell. 
Returnpressed emulates the enter key which moves the cursor onto the next cell.

These work as described above, which is all good, but I am now trying to combine the actions, so that the user only has to press the first key and it inserts the text and then moves onto the next cell.

So when I simply extend the code in the Keypressed IBAction to include the code in the Returnpressed action, it simply inserts a carriage return into the text and stays in the same cell.

What am I missing please?

Here is a code snippet:

```
extension UIKeyInput{
    func `return`() -> Void{
        insertText("\n")
    }

}

class KeyboardViewController: UIInputViewController, AVAudioPlayerDelegate {

@IBAction func KeyPressed(_ sender: Any) {

    let string =  (sender as AnyObject).titleLabel??.text

    (textDocumentProxy as UIKeyInput).insertText("\(string!)")

    **//THIS IS THE LINE THAT FIXED THIS FOR ME
    textDocumentProxy.adjustTextPosition(byCharacterOffset: -1)**        

    self.EnterPressed(nil)

}

@IBAction func EnterPressed(_ sender: Any?) {

    //default action for a return key press
    textDocumentProxy.return()

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fudge this by determining what action s caused textDidChange to fire. It turns out that by simply adjusting the cursor portion, between inserting the text and firing the Return action works.

Not really sure how, but achieves what I want without the the user knowing it is a kludge and no overhead. I have changed the original code snippet to show the fix.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to override the UITextInputDelegate textDidChange method (UIInputViewController implements UITextInputDelegate).It turns out that textDidChange is called when the text changes. And make the first responder to the next text field of your cell.

Comment: Thanks, but textDidChange doesn't fire after I have entered text with my Custom Keyboard extension for some reason. It does fire when I change from my standard iso keyboard to my custom keyboard. Strange